# How to Use a Variable from my Code in a SQL Statement?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm converting a string to integer and than inserting this integer in my post table.

```
int currTopicID = Convert.ToInt32(id.Text);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO post VALUES(currTopicID)", con);
```

The problem is that currTopicID isn't being recognized as an integer when i do the insertion. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter instead:

```
int currTopicID = Convert.ToInt32(id.Text);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO post VALUES(@currTopicID)", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@currTopicID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = currTopicID.Tostring();

//OR   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currTopicID",currTopicID.Tostring()); 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Regards

Comment: I had a problem with this:cmd.Parameters.Add("@currTopicID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = currTopicID;
you can break this into two steps
cmd.Parameters.Add("@currTopicID", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
cmd.Parameters["@currTopicID"].Value = currTopicID;

Comment: Can't recall right now, but it was something to do with incompatible types.

Comment: Is your post field datatype is really an integer? You can choose cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currTopicID",currTopicID.Tostring()); instead so that you do not need to specify its datatype.

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong statement.

Use instead,

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO post VALUES("+currTopicID.ToString()+")", con);
```

Or use a parametrized query.

Comment: Make that **currTopicID.ToString()**

Comment: While this command is fairly safe due to the conversion operation, it's generally a bad idea to insert values directly into the command text. Instead, you should use paramters.

Comment: @Mystrer Man yes agree, actually if you have a method that takes an integer than in that case it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use parameters when passing variables in MS SQL.
Even better use stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a stored procedure with a parameter.  By doing this you will avoid sql injection.